# Flutter errors are ignored

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart

I can seem to find any answers to this, but I find this really strange. If something goes wrong in my Flutter app, for example I'm trying to initialize a list with some null values, the code stops running from after that line. I would expect some kind of error message or something, but NOTHING happens. It just doesnt continue(The breakpoint the line under isn't reached). I tried enclosing the statement in a try catch block, but it doesn't catch it because apparently there isn't an error(?).

To further investigate this, I tried throwing an error where I know the error got wrong, and NOTHING happened. There was no way of me knowing the error had been thrown if I didn't step through the code. Same goes with my assert statements, when something goes wrong, the app doesn't give me any sign of it. Except it stops running through the code, so I have to step through the whole codebase to discover where the problem occurred, has anyone else experienced this?

[image]

Consider the picture below. When run, it will not reach the second breakpoint, and nothing will be shown in either debug/messages, and the app it itself doesn't indicate any error. What am I missing?

Also I'm using IntelliJ 2019.

Comment: What about trace stack? When exeption is happend you can see the stack. Also `debug console` gives some information in which line the exception occured.

Comment: @AleksTi See my updated post

Comment: post your main function of main.dart

Comment: @Darish Why is it relevant? The assert(which fails) should make something happen. It’s just ignored. Why is that?

Comment: Could you please post sample code that all defined in one single main.dart  to reproduce your problem? That would be great for any one to help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25430) at Flutter. This only happens when triggered in an async function.